# How can I disable Facebook button on HTC ChaCha without voiding warranty?

Tags: facebook, buttons, htc-chacha

I'm interested in the HTC ChaCha but I don't like the Facebook button. I'd prefer it to link to my address book or something like that. Is it possible to do that or in the worst case disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this app: [FB ReMap](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.naooh.chacha.remap&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5uYW9vaC5jaGFjaGEucmVtYXAiXQ..) For HTC ChaCha

Comment: ReMap has been removed from the Play store. Any chance of alternative apk download links? Otherwise, F-Button Lite (or the alternative) works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Is impossible for you to attempt to make the change withouth the device been rooted.

According to [XDA Developers Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=1b06d6c49af14165de0850747e7d7516&p=17224372#post17224372), you need to go into your system folder located in your root, to change the keyboard layout file located here: `/system/usr/keylayout/[devicename]-keypad.kl`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Facebook Button for HTC ChaCha](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anmipo.android.fbutton) or its lite version.

It is a normal standard-abiding Android application, which installs from the Market, does not require any hacks, and works on *unrooted* devices — so it'll keep you warranty safe.

Feel free to check also its [support thread on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1440515).